# bash scripting - selectively handle file names with spaces

Tags: bash, filenames, spaces

I have a directory with the files names as "a b c.jpg", "d e f 0.jpg", "g h i.jpg"

I need a script to have all the files ending with "*0.jpg" to become "*_0.jpg"

So, in the above example the second file should become "d e f_0.jpg"

Answer (score 5):

I think your question should read that you want files ending with " 0.jpg" to become "_0.jpg" (note the space in the first quotes). That makes sense with your example.

```
for i in *\ 0.jpg ; do
    mv -- "$i" "${i/ 0.jpg/_0.jpg}"
done
```

That is, for every file matching the pattern "* 0.jpg", rename it replacing " 0.jpg" with "_0.jpg"

Edit: For added safety, consider using `-n` (no-clobber) or `-i` (interactive) as an option to `mv(1)`.

Comment: Good solution, +1. You might want to write `mv -- "$i"` to guard agains filenames starting with a dash.

Comment: Good point. Since we're using bash, we probably have GNU mv. Added.

Comment: hi, please explain which technique you are using here? I don't get it. "${i/ 0.jpg/_0.jpg}"

Answer (score 1):

The `rename` tool might be what you need.

Comment: That's part of MySQL so it may not be installed. Also, it works on the contents not the names of file.

Answer (score -3):

```
ls -1 | grep .jpg | awk -F "." '{print $1 "_0." $2}'
```

Comment: This deserves at least three downvotes. Never use `ls` in scripts, never use `grep` to match filenames, don't use external tools if there is a simpler builtin solution.

Comment: It's worse than that: this doesn't actually rename anything, it just prints a list of new names.  And it doesn't replace " 0" with "_0", it *adds* "_0".  And it does this for all .jpg files, not just those ending in " 0.jpg".  And if any of the filenames have additional period characters in them, it gets even sillier.